# Edit view without highlighting

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, editing, reviewing

So I was recently reviewing [a suggested edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/29808), and it said:

> Included spoiler tags (hopefully got it right)

Well, I hoped they got it right too. I went to click Accept anyway, and crossed my fingers, ready to make a remedial edit if something went wrong.

They got it right. But how was I supposed to know? All I saw was the left, which on hover became the right (may be top/bottom depending on your screen dimensions):

[image: BAD][image: BAD TOO]

and this:

[image: BAD THREE]

There was no way to tell if the text was properly spoilered from the review pane.

I don't like to be kept in the dark. So what I propose is this:

[image: Actual output]

where the actual output displays, still side by side, but what the post actually looked/looks like, before and after.

> ### What do people think about this?

If there is enough support, I will take it to main meta.

---

EDIT - I've just noticed the reopen queue has a view that is similar to what I am proposing - `Question (revised)`. So it wouldn't be much of a step to implement it in the suggested edits queue.

Comment: I'm confused.  What's the difference between "rendered" output and "actual" output?  It seems clear to me on reviewing that edit that the spoiler tags are working correctly -- the images are hidden until hover, at which point they appear.

Comment: @Gentlepurplerain The difference, for me at least, is that you can't see whether the text is going to be spoilered correctly since the text is shown and highlighted by the view automatically. In the actual output I would propose a 'before and after' of the post without any highlighting or outlining.

Comment: This has bugged me many times too! Would be nice to at least have access to the proposed revised source text as a whole, which could be copied into an Ask-a-Question window to see the actual result.